# Time series prediction (GRU) with several meta information

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I'm currently trying to build a deep learning model for time series prediction. For the trainings data I don't only have the actual time series, but also some meta information for every time step of the series.

I'm implementing the model using pytorch. My problem is, that I don't know how to use those meta information to build an embedding layer containing all those information, because it only can be 2d. I know that in keras, it is possible to fit the model when putting multiple time series in a list. But I'm not sure if pytorch has the same option?

It should be the same idea as using word and character embeddings all at once for text classification/prediction. Does anyone have an idea?

Thank you! :3

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by meta information? Something like POS tags?

Comment: I give you an ecample:
My current data, from which I want to predict the next day, is the temperature of the last 20 day. So to predict the next day, I could use as meta information, on which days it rained in the last 20 days.
So the data progression is as long as the meta information progression. They proceed parallel to each other.